# How can I test the update path for my Windows 8 app?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps, windows-store

When I develop for Windows Phone, I am able to side load the current version of the app (version on the Windows Store) and then run the app in development in the same emulator. This give me an idea if the app update work.

I am trying to do the same thing with Windows 8 App but it doesn't work. I side load the current version of the app and then run the app in development and I get the following message: "The app ... is already installed on this machine".

How can I test the update path for my Windows 8 app?

Thanks!

Comment: Change the package name in app-manifest and then rebuild and deploy.

Answer (score 1):

When you build an app from the Windows Store it gets packed up into a an `.appx` file, which, you can submit for certification or side load using the PowerShell script.

When you run it in a development environment (pressing “play” in Visual Studio) it installs an unpackaged version in a different directory. What this means is that you must remove the packaged  version before you can install the unpackaged one.

However, you can build a package and side load that one, as long as the version number is larger than the one already installed:

- In Visual Studio, right click on your project and select “Store” and then "Create App packages...". When asked if you need to build the package for upload to the Windows Store, select "No".
- Choose an output location and enter a version number higher than the one of the currently installed version
- Wait for the project to build.
- Start Windows PowerShell from the start screen, and navigate to the output directory from the above step
- Navigate to the sub directory for the correct build of your app (eg. “MyApp_1.0.1_x64_Debug”)
- Run `.\Add-AppDevPackage.ps1` and wait for the app to install.

This will have upgraded your current packaged install to the new version, which will allow you to test that any upgrade code in your app works, you will not, however be able to debug it in Visual Studio.

Note, that when your done testing, you should use the `remove-appxpackage <Your app ID>` ([Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh856038.aspx)) PowerShell command to uninstall the side loaded version to prevent you from having issues if you try and install a version from the Windows Store.

Hope that's helpful.

-Andy.

Update: I forgot to mention, you may have to run `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` from an admin PowerShell window before you are able to execute .ps1 scripts - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849812.aspx